# Following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Microposts Controller Test Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

when I tested the Microposts controller, this is what it shows:

1st Error:

```
Failure:
MicropostsControllerTest#test_should_create_micropost 
"Micropost.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 3
  Actual: 2
```

2nd Error:

```
Failure:
MicropostsControllerTest#test_should_update_micropost 
Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <422: Unprocessable Entity>
```

Micropost Controller:

```
  class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_micropost, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
    
      # GET /microposts or /microposts.json
      def index
        @microposts = Micropost.all
      end
    
      # GET /microposts/1 or /microposts/1.json
      def show
      end
    
      # GET /microposts/new
      def new
        @micropost = Micropost.new
      end
    
      # GET /microposts/1/edit
      def edit
      end
    
      # POST /microposts or /microposts.json
      def create
        @micropost = Micropost.new(micropost_params)
    
        respond_to do |format|
          if @micropost.save
            format.html { redirect_to micropost_url(@micropost), notice: "Micropost was successfully created." }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @micropost }
          else
            format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    
      # PATCH/PUT /microposts/1 or /microposts/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @micropost.update(micropost_params)
            format.html { redirect_to micropost_url(@micropost), notice: "Micropost was successfully updated." }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @micropost }
          else
            format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    
      # DELETE /microposts/1 or /microposts/1.json
      def destroy
        @micropost.destroy
    
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to microposts_url, notice: "Micropost was successfully destroyed." }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end
    
      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_micropost
          @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
        end
    
        # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
        def micropost_params
          params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :user_id)
        end
    end





User Controller:

    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_user, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
    
      # GET /users or /users.json
      def index
        @users = User.all
      end
    
      # GET /users/1 or /users/1.json
      def show
      end
    
      # GET /users/new
      def new
        @user = User.new
      end
    
      # GET /users/1/edit
      def edit
      end
    
      # POST /users or /users.json
      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
    
        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.save
            format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice: "User was successfully created." }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
          else
            format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    
      # PATCH/PUT /users/1 or /users/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.update(user_params)
            format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice: "User was successfully updated." }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
          else
            format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    
      # DELETE /users/1 or /users/1.json
      def destroy
        @user.destroy
    
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: "User was successfully destroyed." }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end
    
      #show micropost for the user
      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @micropost = @user.microposts.first
      end
    
      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_user
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
        end
    
        # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
        def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
        end
    end


Models:

    class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :user
        validates :content, length: {maximum: 140},
            presence: true
    end


    class User < ApplicationRecord
        has_many :microposts
        validates :name, presence: true
        validates :email, presence: true
    end


Micropost controller test:

require "test_helper"

class MicropostsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @micropost = microposts(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get microposts_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get new_micropost_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create micropost" do
    assert_difference("Micropost.count") do
      post microposts_url, params: { micropost: { content: @micropost.content, user_id: @micropost.user_id } }
    end

    assert_redirected_to micropost_url(Micropost.last)
  end

  test "should show micropost" do
    get micropost_url(@micropost)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get edit_micropost_url(@micropost)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update micropost" do
    patch micropost_url(@micropost), params: { micropost: { content: @micropost.content, user_id: @micropost.user_id } }
    assert_redirected_to micropost_url(@micropost)
  end

  test "should destroy micropost" do
    assert_difference("Micropost.count", -1) do
      delete micropost_url(@micropost)
    end

    assert_redirected_to microposts_url
  end
end
```

How can I fix these errors?

After adding these the @micropost.update!:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.update!(micropost_params)
        format.html { redirect_to micropost_url(@micropost), notice: "Micropost was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @micropost }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Error shows:
Error:

```
MicropostsControllerTest#test_should_update_micropost:
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User must exist
    app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:40:in `block in update'
    app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:39:in `update'
    test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:37:in `block in <class:MicropostsControllerTest>'


Failure:
MicropostsControllerTest#test_should_create_micropost [/mnt/c/code/toy_application/test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:19]:
"Micropost.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 3
  Actual: 2
```

When I tried the application, I can still successfully add a new user and update a post.

Comment: @spickermann added it already

Comment: I suggest temporarily changing `@micropost.update(micropost_params)` to `@micropost.update!(micropost_params)` (note the bang) in `MicropostsController#update`. `update!` will raise an error telling why it couldn't save the record and the error message will tell us why.

Comment: The import part is this `Validation failed: User must exist`. Which means that updating the micropost with `user_id: @micropost.user_id` fails. Which means `@micropost.user_id` must be `nil`. Which means it was already `nil` when it was created. Which means the fixture that is returned by `microposts(:one)` is not associated to a user. Please check your fixtures files and make sure that the micropost fixtures are connected to user and that those user fixtures exist too. I suggest reading about [Fixtures in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures)

Comment: @spickermann I forgot to add but I was able to fix this by changing the fixtures: `one:
  content: MyText
  user: one

two:
  content: MyText
  user: one
`

Answer (score 0):

In Rails fixtures, to reference a model in an association, you can either use a label in the fixture or use an `id` that you specified in the fixture.

For example, using the fixture's label, we can define `users.yml` as the following:

```yaml
one:
  name: foo
  email: foo@one.me

two:
  name: bar
  email: bar@two.me
```

The `microposts.yml` can use the `users` model with the label:

```yaml
one:
  content: MyText
  user: one

two:
  content: MyText
  user: two
```

Alternatively, using the `id` requires specfiying the `id` in `users.yml` as below:

```yaml
one:
  id: 1
  name: foo
  email: foo@one.me

two:
  id: 2
  name: bar
  email: bar@two.me
```

and `microposts.yml`:

```yaml
one:
  content: MyText
  user_id: 1

two:
  content: MyText
  user_id: 2
```

The [official documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html) provides excellent information about that especially the `Label references for associations (belongs_to, has_one, has_many)` section.